# Как задать задний фон для кнопки CustomTkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

Как заменить фон кнопок(За круглыми краями кнопок виден чётный цвет) на фон всего приложения.

```
import customtkinter as tk
from random import *

def random_color():
    clr = f'#{randint(100, 1000)}'
    root.config(bg=clr)
    tk.CTkButton(bg_color=clr)

def disabler():
    if btn1.cget('state') == tk.DISABLED:
        btn1.configure(state=tk.NORMAL)
    else:
        btn1.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)

root = tk.CTk()
root.title('Сменятор цвета')
h = 500
w = 1000
root.geometry(f'{w}x{h}')
root.resizable(False, False)

btn1 = tk.CTkButton(root, text='Случайный цвет',
                 command=random_color)

btn2 = tk.CTkButton(root, text='Переключатель',
                 command=disabler)


btn1.pack()
btn2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Пробовал задавать фон btn1 и btn2 через .config(bg_color=clr), но не получилось.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `.configure` с параметром `bg_color` вот так:

```py
def random_color():
    clr = f'#{randint(100, 1000)}'
    root.config(bg=clr)
    btn1.configure(bg_color=clr)
    btn2.configure(bg_color=clr)
```